# Call a httpsCallable cloud function using Google Cloud Scheduler and pass some data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a callable firebase cloud function that `throws` when it's called without any data.

**/functions/index.js**

```
export.someCallableFunction = functions.https.onCall(someCallableFunction);
```

I want to set up a Cloud Scheduler to ping it and avoid cold starts, whenever possible (I know it's not 100% guaranteed to avoid cold starts).

From: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler/jobs

[image]

Can I do this with callable functions? How can I pass data to them?

Will I need to create a regular `HTTP` request function to schedule calls to it first, and then make it call the `callable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke a callable function without the client library, you will have to follow its [protocol specification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).  Basically, you are going to have to POST to it with a JSON payload.  It's up to you to figure out how to get both the function and scheduler to agree on something that doesn't throw an exception.

It's entirely possible that Cloud Scheduler simply doesn't allow enough configuration to support the minimum required headers required by callables.  In that case, you'll have to use something other than Cloud Scheduler to invoke the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Doug. So `admin.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage')({...someData});` will not work, right? Could you recommend something to avoid cold starts on callables? They take like 5 to 7 seconds to respond when they're cold starting.

Comment: Use another scheduling service that lets you run code that you can use to implement the spec.  You have a lot of options - a web search should reveal some.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily if you know a few specifics, I made a video tutorial on how to do this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBYt4Mphf6E

You need to set the correct headers by using the Google Cloud SDK and launching the job from a console. Body data is also required.